# AngularJS - using ng-model on a checkbox and toggling it on/off through the controller

Tags: angularjs

[Please see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bdkkenp/2/)

In this simple example here I want to set the checkbox value to true or '1' using a controller. I also want to keep a variable called $scope.button within the controller that is tied to the checkbox using ng-model.

However I am unable to set the checkbox value to true or 1 using $scope.button = 1

```
<div ng-app="App"> 
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input ng-model="$scope.button" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular code

```
var app = angular.module('App', [])


app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.button = 1;  

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<div ng-app="App"> 
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="button" type="checkbox"/>
    <span ng-bind="button"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've removed `$scope` from the `ng-model` attribute as this doesn't belong there. It's already being bound to the scope.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bdkkenp/3/